# C# escaping Characters in a datacontext literal string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a combobox whose selection I would like to determine the datacontext of a datagrid.

I have an `if/else` statement that I have set to handle this based on the combobox_Selection changed event.

My issues arrises trying to set the

```
{
     dataGrid.DataContext = "{Binding Source = {StaticResource NameOfXmlDataProvider}}";
}
```

When debugging and looking at the code I see the data context is being set to the entire string including the `"s"`. Placing the @ before the quotes has the same result. Removing the quotes in the `if` statement throws all kinds of errors.

I'll provide simplified code below so you can get a better idea of what I'm talking about.

Note: I am aware some of the bindings referenced are not in the Xaml , they are in my complete code and that is not the issue.

## XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Starting_Over.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Starting_Over"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Field Material Request" Height="700" Width="1200" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Field" Source=".\Data\Groups.xml" />
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Steel Service Meter Installations" Source=".\Data\Steel Service Meter Installations.xml" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <TabControl>
                <TabItem>
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Find Parts to be Ordered" Width="320" Padding="30,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Black" FontFamily="Gerogia"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <Label Content="Select Material Type:" Padding="75,0,0,0" FontSize="14"/>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Field}}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Root/InventoryGroups/ID}" DisplayMemberPath="@name"  SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged" SelectedValue="@name" />
                        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="0,67,0,270" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFBBE4FF" SelectionMode="Single"  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Root/InventoryItem}">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Store_ID" FontSize="14" Width="60" CanUserSort="False" CanUserResize="False" Header="Item" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding XPath=Inventory-Item}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Data_Description" FontSize="14" Width="1350" CanUserSort="False" CanUserResize="False" Header="Description" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding XPath=Item-Description}" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

## CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;

namespace Starting_Over
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var hi = comboBox.SelectedIndex;

            if (hi == 0)
            {
                    dataGrid.DataContext= "{ Binding Source = { StaticResource Steel Service Meter Installations}}";
            }
            else if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                    dataGrid.DataContext = "{ Binding Source = {StaticResource Steel Mains - Maint. Mains}}";
            }
            else if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                   dataGrid.DataContext = "{ Binding Source = {StaticResource Plastic Mains}}";
            }
            else if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {
                   dataGrid.DataContext = "{ Binding Source = {StaticResource Plastic Service}}";
            }
            else
            {
                dataGrid.DataContext = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "{ Binding Source = {StaticResource Plastic Service}}" is a xaml expression. you can't use it in csharp. look at tutorials related to using xml data in wpf.

Comment: Don't use a string approach, use a viewmodel that sets/loads the correct options for you and refer to the view model. If you really want to use your if statement, use new DataBinding instead

Comment: @Dbl I understand its a xaml expression as I use it in the xaml for the combo box binding.  I was hoping to either have the string be read literal or perhaps save it as a variable.  So have the datacontext= Variable name in the xaml and then set the variable in the combox select event.    I suppose im just thinking about this incorrectly in the perspective of c#

Comment: @Icepickle Can you give me a very simple example to point me in the right direction?

Comment: @SBonner yeah. currently you're thinking wrong about it. xaml will be compiled to sharp. while in xaml it looks like you are assigning a string, in fact it is just a syntax which can be recognized and replaced by actual csharp classes. hence the suggestion to look at tutorials. you will see how it is done properly there